# Matrix Multiplication Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to multiply the matrix and came across below code, can someone please help me understand the logic for second 'for' loop, why is it range(len(B[0])). I am quite a  newbie to programming world  so unable to understand the logic. Please help.

```
for i in range(r1): 
    print("i=",i)
    for j in range(len(B[0])): 
        print("j=",j)
        for k in range(r2): 
            print("k=",k)
            result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
return(result)
```

Here r1 and r2 are lengths of two matrix

Comment: B is a list type that is not defined in your above code. In the second "for loop" the loop is iterating through the # of sub-elements present in the very first element of  list "B" which is called as B[0]

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do matrix multiplication is to use numpy dot product:

```
import numpy as np
result = np.dot([[2, 5], [5, 8]],[[2, 1], [5, 9]])
#result = np.dot(matrix1, matrix2)
```